# Light switch is reversed and flipping the breaker

Tags: wiring

I have a ceiling fan in one of my bedrooms that is on when the switch is in the "off" position. It works fine as long as I use the pull chains to use it. But if I turn the wall switch to the "on" position it immediately flips the breaker. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Agree with Ruskes - you or someone you know has changed something recently. Pull the switch back out of the box and show us some pics of what you did.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like there is incorrect wiring at the switch or more likely at the fan connections.
Turning the wall switch to on creates a short and opens the breaker.  It could be wired to the neutral at the fan. (Done in a switch loop, so a white wire got connected with a white neutral)

You have Power and neutral at the fan, so it works with the pull chain.

If you post pics of the wiring under the fan canopy and in the switch box, we can get a better idea.

Comment: Ty, I already replaced the switch hoping that was it. I'll try doing the ceiling fan next.

Comment: I took the fan apart and posted a pic

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the breaker.  Remove the face plate for the switch.  Take pictures showing the wires and screws. Post them to your question.

Remove the two screws holding the switch to the box.  Pull out the switch and take more pictures.

Get a new switch and undo the wires to the old switch.

Replace with the new switch after someone sees your pictures.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like the classic "do not know what a **switch loop** is, assuming all blacks go together and all whites go together up in the fan/light box".  In that case, the light etc. will be on 24x7 while the switch is off, but the moment you turn on the switch you get a dead short that trips the breaker (you hope).

Unfortunately, one black and one white wire would have been previously connected *to each other* and not connected to the light or fan at all.  Since they were never connected to the light or fan, they should not have been disturbed. Now, more work is needed.

Now open up the switch box and confirm that the box only has one cable coming into it, and the black and white go to the switch. If it's not that way, we have problems! Come back with more photos and disregard everything I say below.

Follow the wires back to the cables where they enter the box.  Note that the cables define a black-white pair, so you have pair A and pair B.

All work should be done with the breaker off.  Turn it on only to observe results, then turn it off again.

Disconnect the black and white of pair B from the wire nuts going to the fan. Get some small wire nuts and cap that black and white off individually so it is insulated from everything else and not touching each other. So now you have pair A going hotshot to the fan.  Use lots of electrical tape to hold the nuts on, since they're not really designed to cap off a single wire.   Turn the power back on and see if the fan a) does nothing; or b) is continuously on and only controllable through the pull chain.    If b) then you know Pair A is the power supply from the panel.

If not, go ahead and exchange all that, so only pair B feeds the fan. This will confirm Pair B is the power supply from the panel.

Once you have the fan working but non-controllable by switch, the switch doesn't trip the breaker, and you have a black-white pair from the same cable connected to nothing (not even each other) and that presumably goes down to the switch, now we can proceed.

On these loose unconected wires, if you have the skill to do this, take the nuts and tape off those wires and measure the resistance (ohms) between them. Should be infinity with the switch off, and zero with the switch on.    Now:

Properly mark wires which are "always-hot": This is a code requirement.

- With black electrical tape, spiral around the white wire in the switch box to mark that white wire "black".
- Do the same with the unconnected white wire up at the fan box.

Mark wires which are "switched-hot" (hot when switch is on) - optional.

- With RED electrical tape, spiral around the black wire in the switch box.
- Do the same with the unconnected black wire up at the fan box.
- Do the same with the black wire from the fan which controls the light.

OK, NOW, with all that marking done, cut the breaker and simply "match (new) colors" -  connect supply black to switch-cable "black" (former white), supply white to fan white,  and all those reds I mentioned together.   This will give you switch control of the light, but chain control of the fan.

If you want something different, feel free to place either of the fan's two black wires (one remarked red?) to either the "black bundle" for always-on, or the "red bundle" for switched-on.

Comment: Man,  thank you so much. That did the trick.  This house is an inheritance and I'm trying to fix it up spending as little as possible.  I didn't want to call an electrician.  All the blacks were with blacks,  and whites with whites. When I used a diagram and separated them it fixed everything.  Thanks again.